# Is it possible to get only the time from a object in scheduledLocalNotifications Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to display to my users, when the next localnotification will be, after looking around i found out about scheduledLocalNotifications, wich is an array that store all the notifications my app have created.

I just want to get the Minutes and hours, but when i do a NSLOG on a object in the array, it shows my alot of information.

This is how i access:

```
   UIApplication *meuApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
     NSArray *arrayDeNotificacoes = [meuApp scheduledLocalNotifications];

     if (arrayDeNotificacoes.count == 0) {
     NSLog(@"NO");
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Yeap!");
         NSLog(@"%@", arrayDeNotificacoes[0]);
     }
```

This is what i get back:

> 2013-11-15 13:53:57.300 Timer V[574:70b]
>   {fire date = Friday, November
>   15, 2013 at 4:53:31 PM Brasilia Summer Time, time zone =
>   America/Sao_Paulo (GMT-2) offset -7200 (Daylight), repeat interval =
>   0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire
>   date = Friday, November 15, 2013 at 4:53:31 PM Brasilia Summer Time,
>   user info = (null)}

So how can i get only the hours and minutes, to display to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the fireDate property on the notification:

```
UILocalNotification *not =  arrayDeNotificacoes[0];
NSDate *notDate = not.fireDate;
```

Having the NSDate, just create a formater to display hours and minutes:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:notDate];
```

Comment: `NSDate *notDate = not.fireDate;` :)